# PHP MySQL Advance Search with Check boxes

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build search logic that uses multiple form fields and adjusts the MySQL search accordingly.  My main area of issue is when dealing with multiple checkboxes.  The below gets me close but I get multiple "OR" at the end for some reason. The below gives me `(nema = '1' OR OR nema = '12' OR OR nema = '4' OR OR )` for example.  More OR's are added for each checkbox.  What am I missing or not doing correctly?

```
$rating = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, implode(',', $_POST['rating']));

$q = "SELECT * FROM lekker WHERE height BETWEEN 20 AND 30 ";

if (!empty($rating)) {
    
        $var = explode(',',$rating);
        $rating_count = count($var);

        if($rating_count > 1) {   
            $q .= "AND (";
           foreach($var as $test) {
                $q .= "nema = '$test'";
                for($i=0;$i<$rating_count;$i++) {
                    if($i!=$rating_count-1) {
                        $q .= " OR ";
                    }
                }
            }
            $q .= " )";

        } else {
                $q .= "nema = '$rating'";
        }

}

$q .= " ORDER BY `part` ASC";
```

This is the Select I am trying to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM lekker WHERE height BETWEEN 20 AND 22 AND (nema = '1' OR nema = '12') ORDER BY part ASC
```

Comment: You are open to SQL injections with this code. You should parameterize and use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the second loop and always add OR, then you can remove the last one at the end

```
$rating = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, implode(',', $_POST['rating']));

$q = "SELECT * FROM lekker WHERE height BETWEEN 20 AND 30 ";

if (!empty($rating)) {
    
        $var = explode(',',$rating);
        $rating_count = count($var);

        if($rating_count > 1) {   
            $q .= "AND (";
           foreach($var as $test) {
                $q .= "nema = '$test' OR ";
                
            }
            $q=substr($q, 0,-4);
            $q .= " )";

        } else {
                $q .= "nema = '$rating'";
        }

}

$q .= " ORDER BY `part` ASC";
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of worrying about whether or not you need to add an OR simply add it each time through your `foreach` then trim off the trailing OR after you are done with the `foreach`.

```
if ($rating_count > 1) {
   $q .= "AND (";
   foreach($var as $test) {
        $q .= "nema = '$test' OR ";
   }
   $q .= rtrim($q,' OR ') . ' )';
} else {
        $q .= "nema = '$rating'";
}
```